# Cannot find segmentation fault in insertion sort code for arm-v8 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, insertion-sort, armv8

I have generated an array of random integers between 0 and 256 and I tried to sort them using an insertion sort however at some point along the line I messed up and got an error "segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have no idea exactly why I am getting this but I believe the problem has something to do with the macro j representing a loop counter. I have been working away at this for a few hours and I have been stuck on this for a while.

EDIT: After using the debugger I have isolated the problem to be the line:

bl printf

right at the very end when it tries to print the second sorted value.

I have tried to allocate more ram up to 416 bytes, I have tried moving the top2 loop label around (which is the loop that uses j as it's counter) and the farthest i have gotten is for the program to print the first element of the sorted array and then give the error

```
ALLOC   =-(16+400*1)&-16
        .equ    DEALLOC, -ALLOC
size    = 50
define(arraybase, x19)
i       .req    x20
define(j, x21)
define(temp, w22)
define(sort1, w23)

print1: .asciz "Array[%d]: %d\n"
print2: .string "\nSorted Array: \n"
print3: .asciz "top value equals %d \n"
```

...

```
        mov     i, 0

top1:   add     i, i, 1
        ldrb    temp, [arraybase, i ]

        mov     j, i
top2:   mov     x25, j
        sub     x25, x25, 1

        ldrb    sort1, [arraybase, x25 ]
        cmp     temp, sort1
        b.ge    skip1
        strb    sort1, [arraybase, j]
skip1:  sub     j, j, 1

        cmp     j, 0
        b.gt    top2

        strb    temp, [arraybase, j]
        cmp     i, size-1
        b.lt    top1

printing:

        ldr     x0, =print2
        bl      printf

        mov     i, 0
        ldr     x0, =print1

tprint: mov     x1, i
        ldrb    w2, [arraybase, i]
        bl      printf
        add     i, i, 1
        cmp     i, size-1
        b.le    tprint


        mov     x0, 0
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], DEALLOC
        ret
```

The array should be printed in the random order it was initialized in, then it should print the value at the top of the array, then it is meant to print the sorted array in increasing order.

The exact error message I got was:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This appears after it prints the first value of the sorted array

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to find the faulting instruction and to single step your program. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help.

Comment: I am guessing your `tprint` label should be one more line up, so that you reload `x0` which might have been modified by the `printf` in the previous iteration. A debugger should have shown you that.